# "Unsupported method: SourceProvider.getJniDirectories()" vs "Gradle DSL method not found: 'multiDexEnabled()'"

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-multidex

I have an app that has many dependencies `"Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536" after update repositories.`

Then, I found the solution [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

However, after follow those instructions, I started getting the error `"Gradle DSL method not found: 'multiDexEnabled()".`

Then, I found that the solution was to update gradle, by adding 
`"classpath.'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'" to dependencies.`

Then, I started getting the error `"Unsupported method: SourceProvider.getJniDirectories()"`, and I found many posts saying that the solution is to set gradle back to "0.13.+".

But, gradle 0.13.+ doesn't recognise multiDexEnabled and shows my first error `"Gradle DSL method not found: 'multiDexEnabled()'"`.

I need to use multiDex because of the many dependencies I use and also I use Jni. So, one solution breaks the other one.

[UPDATE] A information that can help: I migrated my project from Eclipse to Android Studio because I didn't find a solution for multidex on Eclipse.

Has anyone had same problem? Is there a solution for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your Android Studio to 9.+ version. Try Help - Check for update. If no one update was found switch to the Canary channel (Help - Check for update - Updates).

Comment: Mmm, I think it's because I'm using a Mac version. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html, it has not support for NDK... There's no update to 9.+ for Mac... :(... Does anyone know a solution to use multiDex on Eclipse?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw you wrote to switch to Canary channel. I found the update. Installing..